# canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg") returns only "data:,"

Tags: javascript, canvas, base64

I convert pictures to base64 encoded strings using a canvas:

```
if (inputImage.get(0).files.length) {
    var image = $("#datatransfer_food_image")[0];
    var image_width = image.naturalWidth;
    var image_width_target = image_width;
    var image_height = image.naturalHeight;
    var image_height_target = image_height;

    if ((image_width > 1080) || (image_height > 1080)) {
        var aspectRatio = 0.0;

        if (image_width > image_height) {
            aspectRatio = (image_width / image_height);

            image_width_target = 1080;
            image_height_target = (1080 / aspectRatio);
        } else {
            aspectRatio = (image_height / image_width);

            image_width_target = (1080 / aspectRatio);
            image_height_target = 1080;
        }
    }

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = image_width_target;
    canvas.height = image_height_target;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image_width_target, image_height_target);

    inputImageName = inputImage.val();
    inputImageName = inputImageName.substring((inputImageName.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1), inputImageName.length);
    inputImageSource = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    console.log("input iamge widht: " + image_width);
    console.log("input image widht: " + image_width_target);
    console.log("input image height: " + image_height_target);
    console.log("input image source: " + inputImageSource);
} else {
    error = true;

    $("#food_picture_missing").show();
}
```

This code is working usually. for example with this picture:

[image]

But if i take this picture for example (also a jpg):

[image]

The value of `inputImageSource` is only:

```
data:,
```

How can that be? What am i doing wrong here that some pictures are encoded correclty and some are just resulting in a string like `data:,`?

**EDIT**

I pick the image using the following jquery code:

```
$(document).on("change", "#datatransfer_food_image_input", function() {
if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
    var image_scanner = $("#datatransfer_food_image_div");

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        $("#datatransfer_food_image").attr("src", e.target.result);
        $("#datatransfer_food_image").removeClass("icon-scanner");
        $("#datatransfer_food_image").addClass("image-upload-image");
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
} else {

}
});
```

**EIDT 2**

```
input image widht: Infinity
datatransfer.js:451 input image height: 1080
datatransfer.js:452 input image source: data:,
```

The image width infinity seems to be the problem.
I added more code.

**EDIT 3**

It showed that the canvas is not the problem. The calculation of the width and the height and the aspect ratio is. If you take the first picture (which is landscape):

```
width greater than height
aspect ratio: 1.3333333333333333, height: 2448, width: 3264
input image widht: 1080
input image height: 810
```

If you take the second picture (portrait):

```
width smaller than height
ratio: 0, height: 3264, width: 2448
input image widht: Infinity
input image height: 1080
```

But it is the same calculation process, so why 0 and not 1.33?

Comment: Do you load the second image from a different external source ?

Comment: No, it is the same source folder.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an issue with the image not yet being loaded, as [the `toDataURL` spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl), "If the canvas has no pixels (i.e. either its horizontal dimension or its vertical dimension is zero) then the method must return the string '`data:,`'" **Please clarify:** what are the values of `image_width_target` and `image_height_target` when this bug manifests?

Comment: The hint to print the `image_width_target` was good. it is infinity. So the problem does not seem to be the canvas it is the recalculation of the size because i only allow a maximum of 1080 x 1080 and i cut them off myself.

Comment: The problem is that javascripts result for `(3264/2448)` is null and ofcourse something defied by null is never good. Why is it 0 and not 1,33?

Comment: No. I edited. See Edit 3. The calculation for portrait aspect ratios returnes 0 but it shoudl return 1.33 (in this case). landscape (the same calculation) the result is correct with 1.33.

Comment: `3264/2448` *is* `1.3333333333333333`. If that's the not the result you're getting, then that's not the math operation you're doing, or else you're losing the result and substituting it with something else.

Comment: It is exaclty that. You can see the math in the code i posted. protrait and landscape is exact the same. for landscape its 1.33 for portrait 0.

Comment: Can you produce a complete runnable example page (JSFiddle, JSBin, Stack Snippet) that reporduces this error?

Comment: Also, what happens if you change your initial `var aspectRatio = 0.0;` declaration to another value like `1`? Perhaps it's never being given a new value, somehow. (I don't see how that could happen in your code, but it sounds more plausible than `3264/2448` yielding `0`. Maybe you misspelled the name and did something like `aespctRatoi = (image_height / image_width);` by mistake?)

Comment: try to set a breakpoint in the else condition and step through to check the values, that should let you spot where the calculation goes wrong.

Comment: Why not use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` instead of reading it as base64?